# How to mount folder inside WSL1 to another mount point inside wsl?

Tags: filesystems, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Inside WSL1 I need to mount `/home/userx/a/b` to `/home/userx/c/d`. On native Linux I do this with

```
sudo mount /home/userx/a/b /home/userx/c/d
```

Unfortunately, on WSL1 this gives me an error message saying:

```
mount: /home/niels/Melusina_Press/Tei-xslt/profiles/melusina: unknown filesystem type.
```

I used `df -Th` to find out the filesystem on WSL1 and it gives me `lxfs`. However, `mount` does not know any `lxfs` filesystem type which I could use for the `-t` option of `mount`

Thus, how would I mount a WSL folder to another WSL folder inside WSL1?

Comment: Why are you talking about a MOUNT??  Even on Linux proper, this is not a job for the mount command unless they are sitting in different volumes.. sure it might work but that doesn't make it the correct tool for the job.  This is a simple soft link with .. `ln -s` .. am I missing something here???

Comment: I already responded to this in the comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your syntax is off for your Linux example.  Even under standard Linux, you can't "mount" one folder into another without the `--bind` option.

So that should be:

`sudo mount --bind /home/userx/a/b /home/userx/c/d`

That syntax works for me under WSL1 as well.  As you are probably aware, this is ephemeral, and will disappear on reboot unless added to `/etc/fstab`.  I have not tested it under `/etc/fstab` under WSL1, but I'm assuming that will work as well.  The syntax according to the `mount` manpage is `/olddir /newdir none bind`.

However, wouldn't it make more sense just to create a symlink?

`ln -s /home/userx/a/b /home/userx/c/d`

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the --bind flag, stupid me. The symlink unfortunately does not work in my situation. The first folder is a folder in which I devlop something in a Git repository, the second folder is part of a complex maven/xslt 'compilation' environment that makes use of the other. For some reason the Saxon engine does not find the content of the second folder in case I just symlink it. Mounting it, however, works. The alternative would be to use a Git submodule within the compilation environment which itself a Git repository. However, I really do not want to get into this either.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Definitely a good use for the `--bind`/`bindfs` option then.